# How to remove hundreds seperator from all prices

Tags: magento2, price, format, magento2.2.8

All prices on the lv_LV store view is displayed with hundreds separator(space) . Tried to change the `<group> </group>` to `<group></group>` in \vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Locale\Data\lv.xml but it does not help. 
Would the changes in following lines help? I have tried some but cannot get rid of the hundreds seperator

```
<currencyFormats numberSystem="latn">
    <currencyFormatLength>
        <currencyFormat type="standard">
            <pattern>¤#,##0.00</pattern>
        </currencyFormat>
        <currencyFormat type="accounting">
            <pattern>¤#,##0.00</pattern>
        </currencyFormat>
    </currencyFormatLength>
</currencyFormats>
```

UPDATE: Some changes to previously mentioned file led to some prices appear correctly, however some still are in format 10 99.99 which is really weird.

Comment: Could you please review this extension https://github.com/mage2pro/currency-format

Comment: Not planning to buy 200 dollar extension for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround for anyone that needs to change price format globally. Might not be the most cleanest way but it gets the job done.

Part of the change must be done within

```
\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Locale\Data\*.xml
```

Where *.xml is the locale file for your particular language. For example lv.xml for Latvian. Find variables that change digital and currency format and remove the unnecessary commas and dots. It might be possible to copy the file to your design folder and do the changes there, however I did not test it.

Additionally you need to write your own module [Mageplaza guide](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/) and extend a function following this [Webkul guide](https://webkul.com/blog/change-format-price-magento-2/)
Within the function you change the $group variable to fixed constant and that will solve the seperation problem.